# htaccess to rewrite ASP to PHP with query string param change

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently changed from an ASP site to a PHP site and I need to rewrite the old URL style to a new style. For example:

```
www.mydomain.com/store/list_view.asp?itemid=1000645
```

To this:

```
www.mydomain.com/store/list_view.php?id=1000645
```

so far I can get an ASP request to redirect to a PHP page using this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ /$1.php [R=301,NC]
```

I'd appreciate any help that you can provide and if possible an explanation of how it works, I'm new to working with redirects and `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^itemid=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.asp$ $1.php?id=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

It matches `QUERY_STRING` for `itemid` parameter and captures it's value in `%1` via `RewriteCond`. Then it replaces `.asp` by `.php` and adds `id=%1` to complete the target URL.